# Does a "Disallow:" rule with nothing following it in robots.txt block my entire domain?

Tags: robots.txt

If my website's *robots.txt* has the following code, does that mean my entire site is being blocked from indexing, or do I need to append the code with a `/`?

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow:
```

Comment: The file must be named `robots.txt`, not `robot.txt`. I edited your question to use the correct name. -- Please also note that robots.txt doesn’t prevent *indexing* (only *crawling*).

Comment: @HenryVisotski: There was an edit conflict (my edit overwrote yours). But I don’t think the question needs the [tag:seo] tag, because it isn’t about SEO (what is better for SEO etc.), only robots.txt knowledge is needed here.

Comment: @unor I'm fine with that. Although the only people who seem to concern themselves with this file 99% of the time are SEO's, so I would argue it falls mostly into the SEO purview. But I'm ok with letting that stand, especially given that the SEO tag is very general. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

The rule as you have it up there allows all user agents to access everything. If you wanted to block all user agents from accessing anything, you would add the forward slash:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

The forward slash stands for your root directory. This command disallows all user agents from accessing your root directory or anything that it contains - which is everything.